# How to remove sound when context menu is opened manually?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

When I manually show a context menu (code below) - system plays a "ding" sound. But if I click a "context menu" key on keyboard - menu popups without any sound.
How to remove sound when I open it manually?

```
void GridKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control && e.Shift && !e.Alt)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        popupMenu.Show(grid, new Point(grid.Width / 2, grid.Height / 2));
    }
}
```

P.S. I have tested it on Win8 with .NET 4.5 installed (4.0 used).

---

Ok, it looks like opened popup menu receives following `KeyUp` event, and plays sound as for wrong quick access key.
This can be silenced by calling `Application.DoEvents()` before calling `popupMenu.Show()`. But I'd like to know if there is better way.

Comment: why in keydown event? try in mouseUp event

Comment: because of technical specification saying this menu should popup when user presses Ctrl+Shift+C

Comment: Maybe you can explain why your app list playing a sound when you "manually show a context menu"?  I can't reproduce this.  What type is `popupMenu`?